# Slow logs are not showing full details

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, percona

I am new to mysql DB.
I have set log_slow_verbosity value to full.

```
root@localhost/(none)> SELECT @@global.log_slow_verbosity;
+-----------------------------+
| @@global.log_slow_verbosity |
+-----------------------------+
| microtime,query_plan,innodb |
+-----------------------------+
```

But I am unable to see innodb,query_plan info in the mysqld-slow.log

Answer (score 0):

(A possible answer.)

Setting a global variable (anyone, not just this one), does not take effect immediately:

- If you set it in my.cnf (etc), it would take effect until after a restart
- If it is set globally (`SET GLOBAL @@... )`, it won't take effect until someone logs in -- he then gets that setting.  (Caveat: Some globals have no "session" counterpart, so they don't act this way.)
- If you set it in your session, it does not apply to anyone else.

If this does not answer the question, please show us precisely how you set it.  And provide `SELECT @@version;`

Comment: Thanks for the responding.

The output of the above query is as below:

```
root@localhost/(none)> SELECT @@version;
+-----------------+
| @@version       |
+-----------------+
| 5.6.41-84.1-log |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

```

I have set log_slo_verbosity using the below log

```
SET GLOBAL log_slow_verbosity='full';

```

Comment: And Today I saw weird in log. ie.. I noticed  innodb, query_plan information only in the  early morning log(at this time nightly backups are taken). But I don't see those info in the log after the 6:00 AM.